# Show that $\inf(f(A)) \geq f(\sup(A))$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

I have to show that $\inf(f(A)) \geq f(\sup(A))$ given that $f$ is a decreasing function and that $A$ is a non-empty bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

In my attempt I showed that for all $a \in A$ you get that $f(a) \geq \inf(f(A))$ (after showing that $f(A)$ is bounded below) and $f(a) \geq f(\sup(A))$ (after using the definition of a supremum). I can't seem to deduce from this that $\inf(f(A)) \geq f(\sup(A))$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is an example to consider as a hint: Suppose $A = (-\infty,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-x & x\in A \\ -100-x & x\ge 1\end{cases}$$ Then, $f(\operatorname{sup}(A)) = f(1) = -101$ while $\operatorname{inf}(f(A)) = -1$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: Good example, although you only need to define $f(1)$ separately. I found all the negatives unnecessarily confusing :P

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I hadn't thought about it in this particular way. But to actually prove it, I am still stuck. Should I give an example of a function or can I prove it just by using the definitions and the properties of supremum and infimum?

Comment: @TedShifrin The function needed to be decreasing.

Comment: @oliverbgp you can prove it just with the definitions and properties of supremum and infimum.

Comment: But it only needs to be defined on the closure of $A$, @InterstellarProbe. So working on the interval $(0,1)$ and defining $f(1)$ separately would suffice.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Okay. But is there any other hint you can give me for the proof because I'm really stuck.

Comment: $$\inf(f(A)) = \inf\{f(x):x \in A\} = \lim_{x \to \sup(A)^-} f(x) \ge f(\sup(A))$$

Comment: @oliverbgp: Note that $f(\sup A) \le f(a)$ for all $a\in A$ because $f$ is decreasing. This means that $f(\sup A)$ is a ______ for the set $f(A)$.

Comment: The second equality is only true because $f$ is decreasing. Ordinarily that would not be true.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe and Ted Shifrin, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $\inf(f(A)) < f(\sup(A))$. By properties of infimum, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $y \in f(A)$ such that $y< \inf (f(A))+\epsilon$. If we let $\epsilon = \frac{f(\sup(A))-\inf(f(A))}{2}>0$, then this implies in particular that $y<f(\sup(A))$. Note that since $y \in f(A)$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $y=f(x)$.

Now use the fact that $f$ is decreasing to deduce a contradiction from the inequality $f(x)<f(\sup (A))$. Continue from there.

---

A proof without the $\epsilon$ definition. Again suppose $\inf(f(A))<f(\sup(A))$. Then by the definition of infimum, $f(\sup(A))$ cannot be a lower bound for $f(A)$. In other words, there exists $y \in f(A)$ such that $y < f(\sup(A))$. As before, since $y \in f(A)$, there exists $x \in A$ with $f(x)=y$. So the inequality becomes $f(x)<f(\sup(A))$ as above.

Comment: Initially I wanted to do something like this, but unfortunately we are not allowed to use the definition with $\epsilon$ just yet, because that's in the next chapter.

Comment: See my edit. It's possible even without using the $\epsilon$ definition.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't really make sense to me... Could you explain it?

Comment: The infimum of $f(A)$ is by definition the greatest lower bound of $f(A)$. Since $f(\sup(A))$ is greater than the greatest lower bound of $f(A)$, it cannot be a lower bound of $f(A)$.

Comment: Okay, but $f(y)$ doesn't really make sense to me because $y \in f(A)$

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Should have been $f(x)$, where $x \in A$ is chosen so that $f(x)=y$.